# Why sequential forward doesn't select same feature as sequential backward?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, feature-selection

I am working on a binary classification with imbalanced dataset of 77:23 proportion.

class 1 is the minority class.

Currently, am exploring different feature selection techniques and that's when I tried `mlxtend's sequential forward selection and backward selection`

Let's say my objective is to select the `best 5 features from the dataset that will result in best value for the metric chosen`

I got the results like below

**SFS best 5 features** = f1,f2,f3,f4 and f5

**SBS best 5 features** = f1,f2,f3,f7 and f8.

I wasn't expecting to see a difference in the best feature output returned between 2 methods.

As it is a wrapper based method, I am using the same estimator (RF) with same hyperparameters for both SFS and SBS but still the output is different.

Is there anyway to know/understand why the output returned by SFS is different from SBS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different algorithms and work in a greedy fashion, and may find themselves in suboptimal solutions. It's not surprising they can have differences.

Comment: thanks, upvoted. when you mean different algorithms, what do you refer to? Because, they simply add on one side (from scratch) and remove on other algo (from full set). What algo are you talking about?

Comment: And if you meant estimator, I am using the same estimator with same hyperparameters

Comment: The algorithms are SBS and SFS. They're greedily searching the feature space.

Comment: I thought `SFS` and `SBS` algorithm only means adding (SFS) and removing (SBS)

Answer (score 0):

The SBS and SFS algorithms do not give the same feature selection because they are greedy, which results in different choices depending on the "direction" (backwards of forward).

The SFS goes forward and combines features with one another, gradually adding one feature at each iteration. It always favors the feature that maximises the combined features score as the next feature to add (that's what we mean by "greedy"). It stops when the desired number of features has been selected.

On the other hand, the SBS algorithm starts with all the features combined, and gradually removes one feature at each iteration. It always excludes the feature that maximises the combined score of the remaining features. It stops when the desired number of features has been selected.

The logic is different between adding the feature that contributes the most to the score, and exluding the feature that contributes the less to the score. That is why the resulting sequence is different.

It would be easier to understand if you manually execute this algorithm on a very simple example. I hope this helps.